# tkinter changeable value on canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to change the text label on a canvas when buttons are clicked.
I want to increase the label by 10 if the button "up" is clicked and decrease by 10 if the button "down" is clicked.

This is my code, but I don't know what to do next:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Sys(tk.Tk, object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sys, self).__init__()
        self.title('SYSTEM')
        self.geometry('{0}x{1}'.format(500, 500))   # dimentions
        self.consumtion = 300
        self._build_system() 

    def _build_system(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='lightgreen',  height=500, width=500)   # dimentions
                 '''changeable value'''
        self.cons = self.canvas.create_text(250,250, text = str(self.consumtion))

        '''button'''
        self.but = tk.Button( text = "UP")
        self.but.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.consumption + 10)
        self.but.place(relx=0.8, rely = 0.7, anchor = "center")
        self.but = tk.Button(text = "DOWN")
        self.but.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.consumption - 10)
        self.but.place(relx=0.9, rely = 0.7, anchor = "center")

       # pack all
        self.canvas.pack()

sys=Sys()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the documented `itemconfigure` method of the canvas to change any configuration option of any object on the canvas.

For example, you could write a method named `change_consumption` that takes a parameter for how much to change the value by, and it can use `itemconfigure` to change what appears on the canvas:

```
def change_consumption(self, amount):
    self.consumption += amount
    self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.cons, text=self.consumption)
```

You would bind to this function like this for the "up" button; for "down" you would pass `-10`:

```
self.but.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.change_consumption(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling error where you call a variable `self.consumtion` but when you try to change it its called `self.consumption`.

Text objects on canvas does not work like normal labels but more like text widgets, keeping track of selections and with methods for selection, deletion and insert. I created a function to change the text and then let the buttons call that function with the desired offset:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Sys(tk.Tk, object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sys, self).__init__()
        self.title('SYSTEM')
        self.geometry('{0}x{1}'.format(500, 500))   # dimentions
        self.consumption = 300
        self._build_system() 

    def _build_system(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='lightgreen',  height=500, width=500)   # dimentions
        '''changeable value'''
        self.cons = self.canvas.create_text(250,250, text = str(self.consumption))

        '''button'''
        self.but = tk.Button( text = "UP")
        # Call on function change_label with amount = 10
        self.but.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.change_label(10))
        self.but.place(relx=0.8, rely = 0.7, anchor = "center")
        self.but = tk.Button(text = "DOWN")
        # Call on function change_label with amount = -10
        self.but.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.change_label(-10))
        self.but.place(relx=0.9, rely = 0.7, anchor = "center")

       # pack all
        self.canvas.pack()

    def change_label(self, amount):
        # Adjust self.consumption with amount
        self.consumption += amount
        # Delete all chars in self.cons
        self.canvas.dchars(self.cons, 0, tk.END)
        # Insetr new text in self.cons
        self.canvas.insert(self.cons, 0, str(self.consumption)) 

sys = Sys()
```

Have a look at [Editing Canvas Text Items](http://effbot.org/zone/editing-canvas-text-items.htm)